# How do I develop my website to work with the "reader" icon on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-devices

This morning I had a look at my blog on my iPhone and noticed that when I view a specific page a <kbd>Reader</kbd> icon comes up next to the URL in the address bar:

[image]

When I press it, I get an interface like this:

[image]

This functionality was completely unintentional (I wasn't even previously aware of it) but I think really nice, so I want to try and implement it intentionally on a few other pages on my website (and other sites that I work on).

How do I work with and enable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any work on your site. This is build-in feature on iOS Safari.

Comment: Yah, but there are obvious criteria to have it initiated (e.g. it only works on some of my pages) and there will also be certain tags that it may prefer etc.

Comment: @Marty Wallace I found this [How to enable Safari Reader on your site?](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader), hope to help you.